Getting 201: ERROR_GATT_WRITE_REQUEST_BUSY, when I tried to write to the same characteristic for the second time In flutter
I am working on a flutter application which communicates with the BLE devices, for BLE connection i am using the flutter_blue_plus: ^1.32.7 library.
I am able to List the Bluetooth devices and connect and pair with the device, but i am receiving error when i try to send commands to the BLE characteristics.
I am getting the following error:
E/flutter (9263): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(setNotifyValue, gatt.writeDescriptor() returned 201: ERROR_GATT_WRITE_REQUEST_BUSY, null, null) when I tried to write to the same characteristic for the second time. 
First I will click on isLinked Button to write a command to a characteristics which gives the successful response
I am getting this error when I click on LinkRing button to write a deferent command to same characteristics again
Below is the error
I/flutter (19243): Write error: FlutterBluePlusException | writeCharacteristic | fbp-code: 1 | Timed out after 15s
I/flutter (19243): Write successful[36, 83, 32, 57, 102, 48, 101, 50, 107, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101]
I/flutter (19243): [FBP] <writeCharacteristic> args: {remote_id: BC:02:6E:AF:D9:5B, service_uuid: b56c04ea-6cba-4dd4-83b9-7f3056a1bac5, secondary_service_uuid: null, characteristic_uuid: 6ae5deca-d2d0-4e13-a662-ad16e9a78dde, write_type: 0, allow_long_write: 0, value: 24532039663065326b2074727565}
D/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP] onMethodCall: writeCharacteristic
I/flutter (19243): Write error: PlatformException(writeCharacteristic, gatt.writeCharacteristic() returned 201 : ERROR_GATT_WRITE_REQUEST_BUSY, null, null)
D/BluetoothGatt(19243): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=BC:02:6E:AF:D9:5B interval=48 latency=30 timeout=600 status=0
E/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP] onCharacteristicWrite:
E/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP]   chr: 6ae5deca-d2d0-4e13-a662-ad16e9a78dde
E/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP]   status: UNKNOWN_GATT_ERROR (133) (133)
D/BluetoothGatt(19243): onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=13 device=BC:02:6E:AF:D9:5B
D/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP] onConnectionStateChange:disconnected
D/[FBP-Android](19243): [FBP]   status: CONNECTION_TERMINATED_BY_LOCAL_HOST
D/BluetoothGatt(19243): close()
D/BluetoothGatt(19243): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=13
I/flutter (19243): [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicWritten ]] result: {error_string: UNKNOWN_GATT_ERROR (133), service_uuid: b56c04ea-6cba-4dd4-83b9-7f3056a1bac5, success: 0, remote_id: BC:02:6E:AF:D9:5B, error_code: 133, characteristic_uuid: 6ae5deca-d2d0-4e13-a662-ad16e9a78dde, value: 24532039663065326b2074727565}
I/flutter (19243): [FBP] [[ OnConnectionStateChanged ]] result: {disconnect_reason_code: 22, disconnect_reason_string: CONNECTION_TERMINATED_BY_LOCAL_HOST, remote_id: BC:02:6E:AF:D9:5B, connection_state: 0}

Below are my buttons
 ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("isWatchLinkedTo");
                    for (var service in _services) {
                      if (service.uuid == targetSensorServiceUUID) {
                        for (var characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                          if (characteristic.uuid ==
                              targetSensorCharacteristicUUID) {
                            sensorcharacteristic = characteristic;

                            String result = "\$S userId false";
                            sensorcharacteristic!.setNotifyValue(true);
                            startListening();
                            _writeCharacteristic(sensorcharacteristic!, result);
                          }
                        }
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("isLinked")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("linkRingTo");
                    for (var service in _services) {
                      if (service.uuid == targetSensorServiceUUID) {
                        for (var characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                          if (characteristic.uuid ==
                              targetSensorCharacteristicUUID) {
                            sensorcharacteristic = characteristic;
                            String result = "\$S userId true";
                            _writeCharacteristic(sensorcharacteristic!, result);
                          }
                        }
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("LinkRing")),

              // ..._buildServiceTiles(context, widget.device),
            ],

Writing logic
 Future<void> _writeCharacteristic(
      BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic, String value) async {
    _enqueueOperation(() async {
      if (_isWriting) return;

      _isWriting = true;
      print("Write successful${Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(value))}");
      try {
        await characteristic.write(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(value)));
        print("Write successful${Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(value))}");
      } catch (e) {
        print("Write error: $e");
      } finally {
        _isWriting = false;
      }
    });
  }



  Future<void> startListening() async {
    subscription = sensorcharacteristic?.onValueReceived.listen((value) {
      print("PairCheck New : $value");
    });
  }

  void _enqueueOperation(Future Function() operation) {
    _operationQueue.add(operation);
    _processQueue();
  }

  Future<void> _processQueue() async {
    if (_isProcessingQueue) return;
    _isProcessingQueue = true;

    while (_operationQueue.isNotEmpty) {
      final operation = _operationQueue.removeAt(0);
      await operation();
    }

    _isProcessingQueue = false;
  }

it looks like error is thrown only when we write deferent commands to the same characteristics again. Can you please help me to debug or understand what might be the issue from my side.
I have tried with sending commands to different characteristics which is working. But when I write to a characteristic for the second time  getting the error
